# Excel VBA Compile error Listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I'm nearing completion on a custom excel workbook. I'm having a irritating issue where the below code works but gives a compile error on load. I've tried searching for the solution but being so new to VBA I'm not even sure what could be causing the issue. It highlights listbox1 but I have listbox1 in the sheet noted.

(Compile Error "Method or Data member not found")

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Sheet2.TextBox1.Value = " "
Dim i As Long
i = Sheet2.ListBox1.ListIndex
If i < -1 Then Exit Sub
Sheet2.TextBox1.Value = Sheet1.Range("C" & (i + 4))
End Sub
```

Thank You

Comment: When you say on load, is it when the workbook is opening? Or is it a form load?

Comment: @MatthewD Workbook opening only, the above code works if you ignore the error or click past it. The code basically pulls a named range from another sheet and if/when a user clicks a line item it populates a textbox with additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably due to the loading of the values into the list.  Try something like this.

Create a global boolean variable

```
Private bDoneLoading as Boolean
```

Set it to true in the workbook open function after anything else you may have i this function

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    'Any other code

    bDoneLoading = True
End Sub
```

Add a check to make sure the workbook has loaded.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

    If bDoneLoading = false Then
        Exit sub
    End If

    Sheet2.TextBox1.Value = " "
    Dim i As Long
    i = Sheet2.ListBox1.ListIndex
    If i < -1 Then Exit Sub
    Sheet2.TextBox1.Value = Sheet1.Range("C" & (i + 4))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! One follow-on does it matter where I declare the global variable?

Comment: Yes, they have to be declared at the top of the code. Above any other subs or functions.

Comment: Ty sir for the assistance, easy solution to a huge headache.